# Layout view graph display not filling frame in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, graph

I'm using ArcMap 10.6.1 and when I create a graph and add it to Layout view it doesn't fill the frame, but only a portion of it. The rest of the graph frame is black, as in the screenshot below.

Is this a setting issue, or is there another way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed through the screen display settings not ArcMap settings. In the computer settings under display or graphics, the scale has to be set to 100%. The default for many computers is 125%. After you've updated your display, restart ArcMap. This time when you add a graph to your layout view it shouldn't have the black border.

(This is an older question but I also had this issue and could not find the answer anywhere)